# How to handle auctions ending at certain timestamp

Tags: postgresql, asynchronous, next.js, nestjs

I have a next.js, nest.js, and postgres application for an Ebay type project I'm working on. When a new auction is created, the createdAtDate and auction duration (3 days, 5 days, etc.) are stored with it. What's the best way for me to trigger all the things that need to be done when the auction ends, such as notifying the lister, the winner, updating auction status, etc.?

Comment: A cron job that kicks off a proces, would do the job. Schedule it once a day or hour and you will be fine.

Comment: @FrankHeikens I'd ideally like to trigger the process as soon as the auction ends, at least down to the minute. Could I use cron jobs for this?

Comment: Yes, you could create a cron job that runs every minute.